# Mix DSL and URI query in Elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, dsl

I'm trying to write a python class that takes a properly formatted Elasticsearch JSON query as a parameter.  So far so good.. however, as part of that class I'd like to also take a "to" and "from" parameter to limit the date range that the query runs over.

Is there a way to combine the JSON for the DSL query along with URI parameters to pass in the date and time constraint?

I know I can limit the time using a range parameter like this:

```
GET /my-awesome-index*/_search
{
    "query": 
    {
        "bool": 
        {
            "must": [{"match_all": {}}],
            "filter": 
            [
                {"range": {"date_time": {"gte": "now-24h","lte": "now"}}},
                {"match_phrase": {"super_cool_field": "foo"}},
                {
                    "bool": 
                    {
                        "should": 
                        [
                            {"match_phrase": {"somewhat_cool_field_1": "bar"}},
                            {"match_phrase": {"somewhat_cool_field_2": "boo-ta"}}
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and that's all well and good.. but, I want to craft my class to make the timeframe a variable.  I also know I can limit the timeframe by submitting the URL like this..

```
GET /my-awesome-index*/_search?q=date_time:[1611732033412+TO+1611777796000]
{
    "query": 
    {
        "bool": 
        {
            "must": [{"match_all": {}}],
            "filter": 
            [
                {"match_phrase": {"super_cool_field": "foo"}},
                {
                    "bool": 
                    {
                        "should": 
                        [
                            {"match_phrase": {"somewhat_cool_field_1": "bar"}},
                            {"match_phrase": {"somewhat_cool_field_2": "boo-ta"}}
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I submit that Elasticsearch only seems to consider the timeframe from the URI and ignores the DSL JSON entirely.

**Is there a way to get Elastic to consider / concatenate the two queries into one?**

I'm considering programmatically making the range query something like this

```
range_part = '{{"range":{{"{}":{{"gte":"{}","lte":"{}"}}}}}}'.format(field,start,end)
```

And then dynamically inserting into any JSON the class takes.. but that seems cumbersome since there are so many formats available for the query and finding where to put the string etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion regarding `q` is right. Quoting from the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-search-api-query-params):

> The `q` parameter overrides the query parameter in the request body. If both parameters are specified, documents matching the `query` request body parameter are not returned.

So `q` and `query` cannot be combined.

As to "programatically making the range query" -- since you don't know in what format you'll receive the queries, the standard approach would be to traverse the query json, find/create the correct bool-must/bool-filter and set the range query there.

But let's take a step back -- maybe your class shouldn't be expecting a pre-baked JSON query in the first place. Why not pass a query config array like

```
[
  {
    "type": "match_phrase",
    "field": "super_cool_field",
    "value": "foo"
  },
  ...
]
```

and build the query yourself? That way you have full control over what gets passed downstream to ES. Plus, adding a date range query would be piece of cake...

Comment: Hey.. thanks for the comment, suggestion and the details from the documentation.  I really appreciate your post.  I was sort of hoping not to have to build something from scratch, but I guess that's what I'm going to end up doing.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot -- I'm glad that it helped. Yes -- looks like you'll have to build it from scratch but having control over what gets passed onto ES is fundamentally good -- "Never trust your users." Hey, BTW? I'm finishing an elasticsearch handbook which, I think, would bring you value. If you [let me know](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV) what topic interest you, I'll let you know as soon as the handbook is out!